pyqtgraph specifying the midpoint of a line
In Pyqtgraph, I want to create a line whose midpoint is specified, and by dragging and resizing the line, the midpoint will also change. please help me.
pyqtgraph specifying the midpoint of a line
I use pg.LineSegmentROI to draw line.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

better create minimal working code which we could copy and run.

if you want to drag and resize then maybe you should search information about mouse events in pyqtgraph documentation.

GraphicsScene and Mouse Events — pyqtgraph 0.13.7dev0 documentation

python - How to connect mouse clicked signal to pyqtgraph plot widget - Stack Overflow
